# TranslateAnimation ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, translate-animation

Im facing the next 2 problems:

1)  When I translate an imageview from outside the screen to inside the screen, when the image is moving the image is cropped, and when finishes moving the imageview fixes and shows ok. Why this is happening?

2)  I use translateAnimation to move an imageview for example from (0,0) to (300,0). 
I have implemented the on touch listener. When I try to move the imageview that translate before, when I try to move with the finger the ontouch not works, but if a touch with the finger in the position (0,0) the imageview moves but the image not shows! I don’t understand what is happening.
I try to move the imageView with the finger in the position (300,0) but not work, and when i touch in the position (0,0) moves. But if i move for example 100 in x axis, the imageview is not in position (100,0), its in (400,0)!! i dont understand what is happening. Something is missing, i think the imageview saves the position that start to move or someting, i dont understand. If i remove the translate animation to that imageview, the ontouch works OK!

I hope I was clear.

Here is my code for problem 1:

```
public void showImageFromOutside(ImageView image){

image.setImageResource(obtenerImagen(cartasJugador.get(0).toString()));
TranslateAnimation animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(100, 425, 100, 525);
animation1.setDuration(800);
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
animation1.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
image.startAnimation(animation1);
}
```

Here is my code for problem 2:

```
public void moveImageView(Imageview image){

animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 300, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(250);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
image.startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        seMueve = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (seMueve) {
            x = (int) event.getRawX() - v.getWidth()/2;
            y = (int) event.getRawY() - v.getHeight();
            v.setX(x);
            v.setY(y);
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        seMueve = false;
        break;
    }
    v.performClick();
    return seMueve;
}
```

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Takes a look:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#property-vs-view

especially to

...another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this.

I think that you  can not use onTouchListener with Animation. You shoulds use ObjectAnimator, its easy.

If your API is lower than 11 you can try with http://nineoldandroids.com/.

Regards